# How to 'enable' and 'disable' buttons

Tags: codeigniter

I have two buttons in view that redirect to

1. own website
2. Customer Website

I am using 'codeigniter'. In this, I want to keep a condition the user can click on the "own website" button only one time. Then, that button should be disabled, i.e, only the "customer website" button should work.
To do this, I want to check if the customer id is present in the database. If yes, (i.e, there is customer id inserted) then, the "own website" button should be disabled.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Include code, .etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply wanting to conditionally set HTML on load of page, you can do so with the below code (change it to apply to your db etc), but if you want to do it dynamically you will need to use a client side language to watch for events.

View Code:

```
// View - Own Site
<button class="button" id="own-button" data-customerId="<?= $customerId ?>" disabled="<?= $disabled ?>">Click Me!</button>

// View - Customer Site
<button class="button" id="customer-button">Click Me!</button>
```

CodeIgniter:

```
function index() {
    $data["customerId"] = "1"; // Just an example
    $data["disabled"] = $this->getButtonStatus($data["customerId"]);
    $this->load->view("ownsite/index", $data);
}

// get current button status i.e. is there anything in the DB
private function getButtonStatus($customerId) {
    if(!$customerId) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->load->database();
    $disabled = $this->db->select("customerId")
                         ->where("customerId", $customerId)
                         ->get("myTable");

    return $disabled->num_rows() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: just use if else statement 
if customerid is there then don't show  own website button else show own website button

Comment: @alexadeal this was just an example of it how it could have been done since you didn't provide any code

Comment: @alexadeal also show/hiding something is different to disabling which was what your question was asking for